# HSV mask for color based image segmentation is not working

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, hsv

I am working on *image segmentation* based on color and for this i am using `HSV` masks but they don't seem to work. Can somebody point out what i am doing wrong because i have tried all the methods mentioned online and it doesn't seem to be working.

I am not sure whether to pass `HSV values` or `RGB Values` in the `inRange()` function of `cv2`. But i have tried both the options.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('colors.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

light_color = np.uint8([[[245,183,22]]])
light_color = cv2.cvtColor(light_color, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
light_color = np.ravel(light_color)


dark_color = np.uint8([[[255,193,32]]])
dark_color = cv2.cvtColor(dark_color, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
dark_color = np.ravel(dark_color)


#light_color = np.array([22,232,245])
#dark_color = np.array([32,218,255])

mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, light_color, dark_color)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(mask)
plt.show()
```

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('colors.png')
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

light_color = np.array([[[245,183,22]]])  

dark_color = np.array([[[255,193,32]]])  

#light_color = np.array([22,232,245])
#dark_color = np.array([32,218,255])

mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, light_color, dark_color)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, can you share it?

Comment: @JoshSharkey no there is no error, the problem is that i can't get the image with desired result after applying the mask. At first i was passing simple RGB values and nothing made sense so i passed HSV values in upper and lower range of color to be masked and still it isn't producing any desired results.

Comment: I don't think it matters whether you use RGB or HSV. I think what you are getting at is you have an issue with masking? What happens when you `cv.imshow('mask', mask)`.

Comment: I think you have to update your question with the exact result you are trying to achieve rather than just the problem you are having... because we are not focusing on the real problem here.